# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW), expecting ',' or ')' in ... on line 2

Tags: php

Llevo literalmente 2 horas buscando una solución a este error (sin contar las constantes desconexiones de mi cliente FTP online).

Código:

```
<?php
$error = array(result => "error", msg => "Alias not specified", url => "https://mc-pe.us/$alias");
$error = json_encode($error);
echo $error;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Puede ser por que las claves del array también deben de ir entre comilladas cuando son cadenas.

Esto

```
<?php
$error = array(result => "error", msg => "Alias not specified", url => "https://mc-pe.us/$alias");
$error = json_encode($error);
echo $error;
?>
```

Así

```
<?php
$error = array("result" => "error", "msg" => "Alias not specified", "url" => "https://mc-pe.us/$alias");
$error = json_encode($error);
echo $error;
?>
```

Acabo de ejecutar el ejemplo y funciona correctamente.

Resultado:

```
{"result":"error","msg":"Alias not specified","url":"https:\/\/mc-pe.us\/"}
```

Comment: Gracias, soy nuevo , por eso porque en json se convierte a https://\/ en vez de ser https://mc-pe.us ? Si hago decode volvera como esta en el array?

Comment: Si,  \  (la barra) es para escapar los caracteres, pero si quieres te pongo ambos ejemplos del resultado.

Comment: Gracias. por otro lado , veo que el estilo del resultado (la letra) es distinto. te doy un ejemplo: kah.me?url=test con el mio mc-pe.us/api2/rec.php

Comment: En mi código la variable **$alias** no la he declarado por lo que su contenido no se muestra en el ejemplo.

Comment: Está bien. Por favor revisa la pregunta que acabo de hacer